# How to get notified on a database change in Oracle using C#?

Tags: c#, database, oracle, notifications, polling

I'm currently working on a requirement that is to "replace the previously developed Polling mechanism for change notifications of database".

Let me elaborate a little:
We have an oracle database where we have put some triggers to get notified for any changes on the table. Using it, we were trying to get changed data and converting it into an XML/Json which is the request-body of an WEBAPI to perform a POST operation in another database.

The new requirement is to skip the polling mechanism and come up with something like "rather than we call the database for notifications, it calls us every time it gets updated".

I did a little googling and everyone suggest for the best approach as:
*Database Change Notifications*. Here I need to grant permissions to Oracle and then create an application in .Net where I can write a callback function for future processing. Until here, I'm good but my question is:

The .Net application I need to create that communicates with the database is required to be a Web application and has to be online always? Can I create a console application to get notified, if yes, how will the database contact my application for any change? What exactly is the internal process going on when the database notifies my application for any change?

Comment: You use triggers that convert changed data to XML/JSON and call a web service on another database. That seems like a push mechanism instead of a "polling mechanism". Can you explain?

Comment: @Martin Schapendonk - We use triggers on the tables from where we need to fetch data. So for every new DML operation, we attached a trigger on the table that internally calls the WCF service. So, its like first we pull new data and then push it to the WCF service.

Comment: IMHO, a trigger does not "pull" data. It is the true definition of push, as it only comes into action when it needs to. It seems to me that Database Change Notification is a very sophisticated form of a trigger :-)